# How to add colours to combobox in extjs with names

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-architect

colours are coming but i cant select them 

`{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    anchor: '100%',
    fieldLabel: 'Mild Color',
    forceSelection: true,
    typeAhead : true,
    name: 'mildColor',
    valueField: 'id',
    bind: {
        store: '{mildcolor}'
    },
    tpl: [
        '<ul>',
        '<tpl for=".">',
        '<li style="background-color:{name}">{text}</li>',
        '</tpl>',
        '</ul>'
      ],

}`

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/DObF7.png]

please someone help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/5093834/ajay-thakur

Answer (score 8):

You can use tpl for customize your combobox template according to your requirement.
Please check below fiddle:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1m9r

```
    // The data store containing the list of states
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
    data: [{
            "abbr": "AL",
            "color":"#E20404",
            "name": "Alabama"
        }, {
            "abbr": "AK",
            "color":"#B2FC00",
            "name": "Alaska"
        }, {
            "abbr": "AZ",
            "color":"#2719F7",
            "name": "Arizona"
        }
        //...
    ]
});

// Create the combo box, attached to the states data store
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
    store: states,
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'abbr',
    tpl: [
        '<ul class="x-list-plain">',
        '<tpl for=".">',
        '<li class="x-boundlist-item listItmes" style="background-color:{color}">{name}</li>',
        '</tpl>',
        '</ul>'
    ],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Comment: please help i cant select them i am using extjs 6

Comment: i edit above question watch my code i can't select values in combobox it just like css

Comment: you want to select color also in display field when select any value...?

Comment: look when i open combo i cant even select any of them data and colors are good store is ready but i dont know why its cant working i wasted 3 hours but no result ;)

Comment: please tell me which version of extjs are you using

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the color in the `combo` add on `change` listener and do this

```
changeHandler: function(combo, nVal, oVal) {
    var oRec = combo.findRecordByValue(oVal), nRec = combo.findRecordByValue(nVal);
    oRec && combo.inputEl.removeCls(oRec.get('cls'));
    nRec && combo.inputEl.addCls(nRec.get('cls'));
}
```